# Geoserver configuration for large layers

Tags: postgis, geoserver, centos, geonode

I'm having problem with geoserver configuration. Currently I'm running geoserver 2.4 on CentOS and Tomcat 6 with 24 cores CPU and 48 GB RAM. I have uploaded 4 layers to PostGIS (PostgreSQL 9.3/PostGIS running on the same machine) and when I want to sync those layers to geonode running geonode command `manage.py updatelayers`, after a few seconds geonode shows exception `URLError: <urlopen error timed out>`. While those errors are shown, all cpu cores are being used to 100%. I think that it's a problem with tomcat/geoserver configuration, could you give me some advice on how to set up tomcat/geoserver to host layers which contain more than 500,000 elements.

Comment: Does each layer have 500,000 rows? How complex are the geometries in each row?

Comment: No, generally I have about 20 - 30 layers. Currently I have uploaded 4 of them where only one have exactly 625000 objects and the complexity of geometries is rather simple, there are polygons composed from at least 4 points. This layer also have about 20 property columns. The rest of the layers are rather simple and contains no more than 20 to 50 rows. The geoetries are also only polygons, but with less properties.

Comment: Maybe you can isolate the problem to a specific layer (e.g. is it really only the large layer - just try uploading and syncing that one). Also, can you put the updates to your question in as part of the question (just click edit below the question) to keep the question intact and make it easier to read and answer?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the Tomcat/ Geoserver logs for errors?  I am curious if there are java memory errors that might be influencing the error you described.  I have noticed CPU and memory go through the roof when caching wms layers on the fly from large tables. Your system is pretty robust but you will need to configure java to utilize the system to your needs.  There is a section in the geoserver docs on optimizing "geoserver in production". Which covers the basics but I often use a tool like Jmeter to load test/tweak the configuration.